# upgrading jetty embedded http server to 9.2.2

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to upgrade an embedded jetty server from version 8.1 to version 9.2.2

Version 8.1 works fine , and everything else being the same, I tried to change just the following snippet to upgrade to version 9.2.2

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? The exception below seems to hint at some kind of bad signature for Comet support dependency org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket. But I have not changed any other dependencies.

There is also an exception for class WebSocketFactory but the class is in the $CLASSPATH:
NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor

---

Old version uses:   jetty-hightide-8.1.0.RC0    -This works OK

```
    final WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(".", "/");
    String webrootDir = "/Users/soler/projects/java_sandboxes/development/src/gov/nasa/arc/uasrp/rums/webroot";
    webAppContext.setWar(webrootDir);
    webAppContext.setClassLoader(WebServerContainer.class.getClassLoader());

    final Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(63000);

    Server server = new Server();
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connector});
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    try
    {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
```

---

New version uses:   jetty-distribution-9.2.2.v20140723    -This causes a "HTTP ERROR 503: Service Unavailable" with the exception below.

```
    final WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(".", "/");
    String webrootDir = "/Users/soler/projects/java_sandboxes/development/src/gov/nasa/arc/uasrp/rums/webroot";
    webAppContext.setWar(webrootDir);
    webAppContext.setClassLoader(WebServerContainer.class.getClassLoader());

    Server server = new Server(63000);
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    try
    {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
```

ERROR: Failed to start Jetty web server.
MultiException[javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet, javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature., javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature., javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:549)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1101)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:501)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:58)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:549)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1101)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:501)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:58)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:549)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1101)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:501)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:58)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:549)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comet support class org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket has bad signature.
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:233)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:296)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:284)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:1101)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:501)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:229)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at org.atmosphere.container.JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.(JettyAsyncSupportWithWebSocket.java:58)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketFactory$Acceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.touchkit.RumsTouchServlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.BaseHolder.doStart(BaseHolder.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startJetty(WebServerContainer.java:207)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.WebServerContainer.startWebServer(WebServerContainer.java:58)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.(RumsComponent.java:36)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.rums.RumsComponent.getRumsComponentInstance(RumsComponent.java:53)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.(UASRP.java:143)
    at gov.nasa.arc.uasrp.mui.UASRP.main(UASRP.java:284)